# Group categories based on values from df.groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to group again my grouped data from df.groupby. On my data frame, I grouped my languages column by counting its row occurrences. Below is my code:

`grouped = df_covid_qua.groupby('LANG')['ID'].count()`

`grouped` data works as expected. Below is its output:

```
LANG
ar       2
en     631
es      10
et       1
fr       8
hi      22
in       5
it       1
ja       1
kn       5
ko       3
mr       1
nl       1
pa       1
ta       3
te       1
th       2
tl       1
tr       2
uk       1
und     31
ur       6
```

I'm using the above data for a bar chart. My problem is, there's too much language categories so I decided to group the categories again based on its output. My **expected output** is like this:

```
LANG
en     631
und    31
hi     22
es     10
fr     8
LANG A 5
LANG B 3
LANG C 2
LANG D 1
```

Categories LANG A, B, C and D are languages I would like to group because they have similar count values from the earlier groupby data. I researched about the group apply and combine technique but I'm not sure if it is applicable to my problem.

I'm really new to Python and any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: So what is the grouping criteria?

Comment: Hello @HenryYik, I'd like to combine languages (category) with same count values (from the groupby data) so there will be less categories. I can do this using using data viz tools but I find it confusing using python. Any tips? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
s = df_covid_qua.groupby('LANG')['ID'].count()

#first sort output
s = s.sort_values(ascending=False)

#specify how many last unique values is replaced
N = 4
#remove duplicates and get last smallest values with swap order of values
v = s.drop_duplicates().nsmallest(N).iloc[::-1]

#generate LANG A,B,C dynalically by length
import string
a = string.ascii_uppercase

d = {y: f'LANG {x}' for x, y in zip(a, v)}
print (d)

#create new Series with map by langs
new = pd.Series(v.to_numpy(), index=v.map(d))
```

---

```
#filter values out of smallest and join new Series
out = pd.concat([s[~s.isin(v)], new])
print (out)

en        631
und        31
hi         22
es         10
fr          8
ur          6
LANG A      5
LANG B      3
LANG C      2
LANG D      1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hello jezrael! Thank you very much for these codes. I'll apply this, study the codes and will get back to you soon for any clarifications/questions. Thanks again!

Comment: I don't see LANG A B C D in your data. Please provide the data

Comment: @SaniyaParveez - Data are generated from `a = string.ascii_uppercase`